# Image links not rendering as html (left as [img] on blog)

Tags: keystonejs

Have set up keystone.js to use cloudinary for images. The upload on the editor seems to work, I can see the file in the editor and on cloudinary. (Proof below)

http://res.cloudinary.com/keystone-demo/image/upload/v1473696039/y5v9oewncmuopq4d3vwi.jpg

Used the standard settings as per the documentation on the webpage, changes from the keystone.js file below:

```
'wysiwyg override toolbar': false,
'wysiwyg menubar': true,
'wysiwyg skin': 'lightgray',
'wysiwyg cloudinary images': true,
'wysiwyg additional buttons': 'searchreplace visualchars,'
+ ' charmap ltr rtl pagebreak paste, forecolor backcolor,'
+' emoticons media, preview print ',
'wysiwyg additional plugins': 'example, table, advlist, anchor,'
+ ' autolink, autosave, bbcode, charmap, contextmenu, '
+ ' directionality, emoticons, fullpage, hr, media, pagebreak,'
+ ' paste, preview, print, searchreplace, textcolor,'
+ ' visualblocks, visualchars, wordcount',
```

However, the editor does not use the  type link, but changes it to [img]. This does work in the editor window:

```
[img]http://res.cloudinary.com/keystone-demo/image/upload/v1473696039/y5v9oewncmuopq4d3vwi.jpg[/img]
```

Problem is that when you open up the blog, you get

```
[img]http://res.cloudinary.com/keystone-demo/image/upload/v1473696039/y5v9oewncmuopq4d3vwi.jpg[/img]
```

(example can be seen on my webpage: http://www.constructmind.com/blog/post/overview-of-the-uk-intergovernmental-agreement-for-fatca-implementation)

I checked the documentation and cant find anything.

================= UPDATE re generated HTML from post and blog ====================

post:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Construct Mind</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="/styles/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!--Favicon-->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicon//apple-icon-60x60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicon//apple-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicon//apple-icon-76x76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/favicon//apple-icon-114x114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/favicon//apple-icon-120x120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/favicon//apple-icon-144x144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/favicon//apple-icon-152x152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon//apple-icon-180x180.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/favicon//android-icon-192x192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon//favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon//favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon//favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/favicon//manifest.json">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicon//ms-icon-144x144.png">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">




        <link href="/keystone/styles/content/editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/js/timeline.0e3df5929a60596ace3c16fb0b38e6f9.js"></script></head>
    <body ng-app="cmApp" class="ng-scope">
    <div id="page" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/bg/lonsky.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: -380px 0px;" class="fill ng-scope" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">


        <div id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-constructmind">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img id="construct-logo" class="navbar-logo" src="/images/logo/CS-logo-title-227x100.png"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active" href="/" class="">About us</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="partners" ui-sref-active="active" href="/partners">Partners</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="philosophy" ui-sref-active="active" href="/philosophy">Philosophy</a>
                                                    </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Published <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="blog" ui-sref-active="active" href="/blog/" class="">Articles</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="socialmedia" ui-sref-active="active" href="/socialmedia" class="">Social Media</a>
                                                    </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a ui-sref="contact" ui-sref-active="active" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                                        </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body" style="margin-top: 25px; height: 518px;">
            <!--
                Flash messages allow you to display once-off status messages to users, e.g. form
                validation errors, success messages, etc
            -->
            <!-- The content block should contain the body of your template's content-->
            <!-- uiView: --><ui-view class="ng-scope"><div class="container ng-scope">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 wtransparent">
            <article>
                <p><a ui-sref="blog" href="/blog/">← back to the blog</a></p>
                <hr>
                <header>
                    <h1>Images test </h1>
                    <h5>


                    </h5>
                </header>
                <div class="post">
                    <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                    <br><br><br><br>
[img]http://res.cloudinary.com/keystone-demo/image/upload/v1473839295/mfi8mbb2bq20jd7sht6t.jpg[/img]
<br>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</ui-view>
        </div>
            <div id="footerwrap" class="container footer-constructmind">
                <div id="footer" style="width:100%; margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; height: 50px;">
                    <p></p>
                    <p>
                    <span style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
                        <a href="http://constructmind.com" target="_blank">© Constructmind 2016</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                            <a href="/keystone/signout">Sign Out</a>
                    </span>
                        <span style="float: right; padding-right: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">
                        <a href="mailto:contact@constructmind.com" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="/images/logos/png/40px/website.png"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/BengtBjorkberg" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="/images/logos/png/40px/linkedin.png"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://plus.google.com/108193570873442725868" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="/images/logos/png/40px/googleplus.png"></a>&nbsp;<a href="skype:vrghost-242?call" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="/images/logos/png/35px/skype.png"></a>
                    </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>



    </div>



    <!-- END Javascript -->

    <!--START Google Analytics-->

    <!--END Google Analytics-->

    <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script src="/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/keystone/js/content/editor.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-61636453-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    <script src="/javascripts/constructmind.js"></script>

<iframe id="rufous-sandbox" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none;"></iframe></body></html>
```

blog:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Construct Mind</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="/styles/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!--Favicon-->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicon//apple-icon-60x60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicon//apple-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicon//apple-icon-76x76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/favicon//apple-icon-114x114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/favicon//apple-icon-120x120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/favicon//apple-icon-144x144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/favicon//apple-icon-152x152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon//apple-icon-180x180.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/favicon//android-icon-192x192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon//favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon//favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon//favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/favicon//manifest.json">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicon//ms-icon-144x144.png">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">




        <link href="/keystone/styles/content/editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/js/timeline.0e3df5929a60596ace3c16fb0b38e6f9.js"></script></head>
    <body ng-app="cmApp" class="ng-scope">
    <div id="page" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/bg/lonsky.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: -285px 0px;" class="fill ng-scope" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">


        <div id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-constructmind">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img id="construct-logo" class="navbar-logo" src="/images/logo/CS-logo-title-227x100.png"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active" href="/" class="">About us</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="partners" ui-sref-active="active" href="/partners">Partners</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="philosophy" ui-sref-active="active" href="/philosophy">Philosophy</a>
                                                    </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Published <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="blog" ui-sref-active="active" href="/blog/" class="active">Articles</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a ui-sref="socialmedia" ui-sref-active="active" href="/socialmedia" class="">Social Media</a>
                                                    </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a ui-sref="contact" ui-sref-active="active" href="/contact">Contact</a>
                                        </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body" style="margin-top: 25px; height: 518px;">
            <!--
                Flash messages allow you to display once-off status messages to users, e.g. form
                validation errors, success messages, etc
            -->
            <!-- The content block should contain the body of your template's content-->
            <!-- uiView: --><ui-view class="ng-scope"><div class="container ng-scope">
    <h1>Blog</h1>
</div>
<div class="container ng-scope">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 ctransparent">
            <h4 class="text-weight-normal">Showing 2 post.</h4>
            <div class="blog">
                <div data-ks-editable="" class="post wtransparent">
                    <h2><a ui-sref="post({articletitle: 'implementing-fatca-all-over' })" href="/blog/post/implementing-fatca-all-over">Implementing FATCA all over</a></h2>
                    <p class="lead text-muted">Posted in <a href="/blog/regulatory">Regulatory</a>
                            by Bengt
                    </p>
                    <img src="" class="img pull-right">
                    <p></p><p><span style="color: #333333; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-align: justify;">DBFS was engaged by one of the worlds leading global brokers to consult on the implementation of FATCA for more than 200 entities in over 30 jurisdictions. In this paper we share some of the lessons learnt from undertaking an implementation of this size and, whilst this project was specific to FATCA, we believe that the same issues and solutions will be relevant when implementing OECD Common Reporting Standard and DAC over the next year.</span></p><p></p>
                    <p class="read-more"><a ui-sref="post({articletitle: 'implementing-fatca-all-over' })" href="/blog/post/implementing-fatca-all-over">Read more...</a></p>
                </div>
                <div data-ks-editable="" class="post wtransparent">
                    <h2><a ui-sref="post({articletitle: 'images-test' })" href="/blog/post/images-test">Images test </a></h2>
                    <p class="lead text-muted">
                            by Bengt
                    </p>
                    <img src="" class="img pull-right">
                    <p><br><br><br><br>
Testing imaegs
<br></p>
                    <p class="read-more"><a ui-sref="post({articletitle: 'images-test' })" href="/blog/post/images-test">Read more...</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <div style="margin-top: 70px;" class="list-group">
                <a href="/blog" class="active list-group-item">All Categories</a>
                <a ui-sref="blog({category: 'Regulatory' })" class="false list-group-item" href="/blog/Regulatory">Regulatory</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled">
            <a ui-sref="blog({page 'false' })">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="/blog?page=1">1</a></li>

        <li class="disabled">
            <a ui-sref="blog({page 'false' })">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</ui-view>
        </div>
            <div id="footerwrap" class="container footer-constructmind">
                <div id="footer" style="width:100%; margin: 0px; padding-top: 10px; height: 50px;">
                    <p></p>
                    <p>
                    <span style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
                        <a href="http://constructmind.com" target="_blank">© Constructmind 2016</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                            <a href="/keystone/signout">Sign Out</a>
                    </span>
                        <span style="float: right; padding-right: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">
                        <a href="mailto:contact@constructmind.com" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="/images/logos/png/40px/website.png"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/BengtBjorkberg" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="/images/logos/png/40px/linkedin.png"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://plus.google.com/108193570873442725868" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="/images/logos/png/40px/googleplus.png"></a>&nbsp;<a href="skype:vrghost-242?call" style="border-width:0px; border:0px; text-decoration: none;"><img width="25" height="25" style="border: none; width: 25px; max-width: 25px !important; height: 25px; max-height: 25px !important;" src="/images/logos/png/35px/skype.png"></a>
                    </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>



    </div>



    <!-- END Javascript -->

    <!--START Google Analytics-->

    <!--END Google Analytics-->

    <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script src="/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/keystone/js/content/editor.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-61636453-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    <script src="/javascripts/constructmind.js"></script>

<iframe id="rufous-sandbox" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none;"></iframe></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn off the `bbcode` plugin, it is responsible for the conversion to `[img]`.

Comment: That was really not my intention... OK, on a more serious note, I think bbcode plugin is working in the editor (via the keystone interface signed in), however, I can't find any way of tellind ./blog or /blog/post interface. I can see that post wants to load editor if I am logged in as editor, but not certain what part of keystone "renders" the posts. I have added the rendered HTML for post for clarity. It is from when I am logged in. But logged in or not, it does not seem to go via bbcode?

Comment: @vrghost I don't understand what you mean. In the wysiwyg plugins section, you have `bbcode` as a plugin, and it converts urls to `[img]` while you are editing the post. Anything that happens after that just assumes that the post is valid html.

Comment: OK, I am an idiot, I thought you meant I had turned it of, my bad. By the way, that block of settings was copied form the settings section for wysisyg on keystone.js. Might be worth removing it?

Comment: So if this is the correct answer, it's nice if you mark it as such :P